# What's another word for 'the only option?'

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

Looking for a specific word for 'the only option?' Phrase in my head is:

> Graduating from college shouldn't be the ________ in telling whether a person will be successful.

For some reason, I have zero-sum/end-sum in my head but I am not convinced that is the right word — but perhaps sounds like it.

Comment: Shouldn’t be the ***be-all and end-all*** in determining ...

Comment: ... shouldn’t be the _essential factor_ in determining ...

Comment: the only criterion.

Comment: Are you talking about options that lead to success or options for *telling whether* someone will be successful? Your sentence is confusing.

Comment: *litmus test*....

Comment: 'Graduating from college shouldn't be the only option/factor in telling ...' probably needs rewriting to, say, 'Graduating from college isn't the only factor involved in determining ...' or  'Graduating from college shouldn't be the only factor considered when forecasting ...'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Decisive / deciding / determining factor**, according to [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decisive/deciding/determining%20factor):

> the most important reason

Their example sentence:

> Cost was the decisive/deciding/determining factor in their decision.

Attribution: "Decisive/deciding/determining Factor." Merriam-Webster. Accessed June 13, 2018. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decisive/deciding/determining factor.

Answer (score 0):

**yardstick**. [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/yardstick?s=t)

any standard of measurement or judgment:
"Test scores are not the only yardstick of academic achievement."

As in:

> Graduating from college shouldn't be the only **yardstick** telling
>   whether a person will be successful.